# Is there a vim equivalent to emacs's x-symbol?

Tags: vim, plugins, syntax, formatting

I am working on writing a vim plugin and I would like to have some way of displaying some tokens in the buffer using an alternative glyph to improve readability.  Is there an existing approach to this problem?  Is it even possible within vim?

What I have in mind is something like the emacs package x-symbol -- http://x-symbol.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 3):

You'd get the very basics with

```
:se list
```

and the `listchars` option.

That is not very extensible though. For more involved work you can create concealing syntax rules:

#### Concealing

See

```
:he syn-conceal
:he 'cole'
:he hl-Conceal
```

Excerpts:

#### Syntax Rules

> ```
>  conceal                      *conceal* *:syn-conceal*
>
> When the "conceal" argument is given, the item is marked as concealable.
> Whether or not it is actually concealed depends on the value of the
> 'conceallevel' option.  The 'concealcursor' option is used to decide whether
> concealable items in the current line are displayed unconcealed to be able to
> edit the line.
>
> concealends                       *:syn-concealends*
> ```

```
When the "concealends" argument is given, the start and end matches of
the region, but not the contents of the region, are marked as concealable.
Whether or not they are actually concealed depends on the setting on the
'conceallevel' option. The ends of a region can only be concealed separately
in this way when they have their own highlighting via "matchgroup"
```

> ```
> cchar                         *:syn-cchar*
> ```

```
The "cchar" argument defines the character shown in place of the item
when it is concealed (setting "cchar" only makes sense when the conceal
argument is given.) If "cchar" is not set then the default conceal
character defined in the 'listchars' option is used. Example: >
   :syntax match Entity "&amp;" conceal cchar=&

See |hl-Conceal| for highlighting.
```

#### Conceal Level

> ```
>  'conceallevel' 'cole'        *'conceallevel'* *'cole'*
>
>         number (default 0)
>         local to window
>         {not in Vi}
>         {not available when compiled without the |+conceal|
>         feature}
> Determine how text with the "conceal" syntax attribute |:syn-conceal|
> is shown:
> ```

```
Value       Effect ~
0       Text is shown normally
1       Each block of concealed text is replaced with one
        character.  If the syntax item does not have a custom
        replacement character defined (see |:syn-cchar|) the
        character defined in 'listchars' is used (default is a
        space).
        It is highlighted with the "Conceal" highlight group.
2       Concealed text is completely hidden unless it has a
        custom replacement character defined (see
        |:syn-cchar|).
3       Concealed text is completely hidden.

Note: in the cursor line concealed text is not hidden, so that you can
edit and copy the text.  This can be changed with the 'concealcursor'
option.
```